# Sql query with multiple sub query

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I am trying to do an sql query that will help me to acheive the following result:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RowNum |      email      |    point_1    |    point_2    |  total_point  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1    |  abc@gmail.com  |      120      |      70       |      190      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Sql query statement 1 (to get the value of RowNum, email and point_1):

```
    $sql = "
            select * 
            from 
            (
                 select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY m.first_name) as **RowNum**,
                 ltrim(rtrim(m.email_addr)) AS **email**,
                 CAST(isnull(p.points_accumulated,'0') AS INT) AS **point_1**

                 FROM (select * from crm_member_list where coy_id='HSG' and mbr_id not in (select mbr_id from o2o_tmp_mbr_issues_exclude) ) m
                    left join (select * from crm_member_points where coy_id='HSG') p
                    on p.mbr_id = m.mbr_id
                    where m.email_addr = 'abc@gmail.com'

                    and m.date BETWEEN '2016-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-08-31 23:59:00'
                )sub where RowNum>? and RowNum<?  order by RowNum";
```

Sql query statement 2 (to get the value of point_2):

```
    $sql = "
            select CAST(isnull(p.points_accumulated,'0') AS INT) AS **point_2** 
                    FROM (select * from crm_member_list where coy_id='HSG' and mbr_id not in (select mbr_id from o2o_tmp_mbr_issues_exclude) ) m
                            left join (select * from crm_member_points where coy_id='HSG') p
                            on p.mbr_id = m.mbr_id
                            where m.email_addr = 'abc@gmail.com'
                            and m.date BETWEEN '2016-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-09-30 23:59:00'";
```

I tried to combine the 2 statements shown above to get the result, but I am getting the error of

> "execute sql directly, no cursor".

Combined code:

```
$sql = "
                select * 
                from 
                (
                     (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY m.first_name) as **RowNum**,
                     ltrim(rtrim(m.email_addr)) AS **email**,
                     CAST(isnull(p.points_accumulated,'0') AS INT) AS **point_1**

                     FROM (select * from crm_member_list where coy_id='HSG' and mbr_id not in (select mbr_id from o2o_tmp_mbr_issues_exclude) ) m
                        left join (select * from crm_member_points where coy_id='HSG') p
                        on p.mbr_id = m.mbr_id
                        where m.email_addr = 'abc@gmail.com'
                        and m.date BETWEEN '2016-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-08-31 23:59:00'), 





                    (select CAST(isnull(p.points_accumulated,'0') AS INT) AS **point_2** 
                    FROM (select * from crm_member_list where coy_id='HSG' and mbr_id not in (select mbr_id from o2o_tmp_mbr_issues_exclude) ) m
                            left join (select * from crm_member_points where coy_id='HSG') p
                            on p.mbr_id = m.mbr_id
                            where m.email_addr = 'abc@gmail.com'
                            and m.date BETWEEN '2016-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-09-30 23:59:00'
                    )
               )sub where RowNum>? and RowNum<?  order by RowNum";
```

How should I go about combining both of the query statements to generate the result shown above? And how do I add the column of point_1 and point_2 to get the total_point column?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not mysql, it doesn't support `row_number()`. Please tag with the correct DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly (and assuming you aren't using `mysql` as it doesn't support `row_number`), one approach would be to use `conditional aggregation`.  I also think you are actually looking to `sum` the points for each month versus selecting 1 from each month:

```
select *, row_number() over (order by first_name) rn
from (
    select 
        m.first_name,
        ltrim(rtrim(m.email_addr)) AS email,
        sum(case when m.date >= '2016-08-01' AND m.Date < '2016-09-01' 
                 then CAST(isnull(p.points_accumulated,'0') AS INT)
            end
           ) as point_1,
        sum(case when m.date >= '2016-09-01' AND m.Date < '2016-10-01' 
                 then CAST(isnull(p.points_accumulated,'0') AS INT)
            end
           ) as point_2,
        sum(CAST(isnull(p.points_accumulated,'0') AS INT))
    from crm_member_list m 
        left join crm_member_points p on m.coy_id = p.coy_id 
                                     and p.mbr_id = m.mbr_id
    where m.coy_id = 'HSG' 
          and m.mbr_id not in (select mbr_id from o2o_tmp_mbr_issues_exclude) 
          and m.date >= '2016-08-01' AND m.date < '2016-10-01'
    group by 1, 2
) t
```

Please note I've changed your `between` statement to use `<` and `>=`.  Less chance for issues with this approach.